# How to Determine Winner in Connect Four Game

Tags: python

I've a relatively new beginner to python who just wants to learn as much as he can and to just fiddle around with the language. I've began to make my own Connect Four game, and everything's all right except the identification of a winner when 4 pieces are in a row (whether it be row-wise, column-wise, or diagonal-wise) In my winner(board) function, I've first tested out a win for a row. Please see my winner(board) function below:

```
import random


def winner(board):
    """This function accepts the Connect Four board as a parameter.
    If there is no winner, the function will return the empty string "".
    If the user has won, it will return 'X', and if the computer has
    won it will return 'O'."""
    for row in range(4):
        if (board[row][0] == board[row][1] == board[row][2]) == board[row][3] and \
                (board[row][0] != " "):
            return board[row][0]

    for col in range(4):
        if (board[0][col] == board[1][col] == board[2][col]) == board[3][col] and \
                (board[row][0] != " "):
            return board[0][col]

    # No winner: return the empty string
    return ""


def display_board(board):
    """This function accepts the Connect Four board as a parameter.
    It will print the Connect Four board grid (using ASCII characters)
    and show the positions of any X's and O's.  It also displays
    the column numbers on top of the board to help
    the user figure out the coordinates of their next move.
    This function does not return anything."""

    print("   0   1   2   3   4   5   6")
    print("   " + board[0][0] + " | " + board[0][1] + " | " + board[0][2] + " | " + board[0][3] + " | " + board[0][
        4] + " | " + board[0][5] + " | " + board[0][6])
    print("  ---+---+---+---+---+---+---")
    print("   " + board[1][0] + " | " + board[1][1] + " | " + board[1][2] + " | " + board[1][3] + " | " + board[1][
        4] + " | " + board[1][5] + " | " + board[1][6])
    print("  ---+---+---+---+---+---+---")
    print("   " + board[2][0] + " | " + board[2][1] + " | " + board[2][2] + " | " + board[2][3] + " | " + board[2][
        4] + " | " + board[2][5] + " | " + board[2][6])
    print("  ---+---+---+---+---+---+---")
    print("   " + board[3][0] + " | " + board[3][1] + " | " + board[3][2] + " | " + board[3][3] + " | " + board[3][
        4] + " | " + board[3][5] + " | " + board[3][6])
    print("  ---+---+---+---+---+---+---")
    print("   " + board[4][0] + " | " + board[4][1] + " | " + board[4][2] + " | " + board[4][3] + " | " + board[4][
        4] + " | " + board[4][5] + " | " + board[4][6])
    print("  ---+---+---+---+---+---+---")
    print("   " + board[5][0] + " | " + board[5][1] + " | " + board[5][2] + " | " + board[5][3] + " | " + board[5][
        4] + " | " + board[5][5] + " | " + board[5][6])
    print("  ---+---+---+---+---+---+---")
    print("   " + board[6][0] + " | " + board[6][1] + " | " + board[6][2] + " | " + board[6][3] + " | " + board[6][
        4] + " | " + board[6][5] + " | " + board[6][6])
    print()


def make_user_move(board):
    """This function accepts the Connect Four board as a parameter.
    It will ask the user for a row and column.  If the row and
    column are each within the range of 0 and 6, and that square
    is not already occupied, then it will place an 'X' in that square."""

    valid_move = False
    while not valid_move:
        try:
            col = int(input("What col would you like to move to (0-6):"))
            if board[0][col] != ' ':
                print("Sorry, that column is full. Please try again!\n")
            else:
                for row in range(6, -1, -1):
                    if board[row][col] == ' ' and not valid_move:
                        board[row][col] = 'X'
                        valid_move = True
        except:
            ValueError

    return board


def make_computer_move(board):
    """This function accepts the Connect Four board as a parameter.
    It will randomly pick row and column values between 0 and 6.
    If that square is not already occupied it will place an 'O'
    in that square.  Otherwise, another random row and column
    will be generated."""
    computer_valid_move = False
    while not computer_valid_move:
        col = random.randint(0, 6)
        if board[0][col] != ' ':
            print("Sorry, that column is full. Please try again!\n")
        else:
            for row in range(6, -1, -1):
                if board[row][col] == ' ' and not computer_valid_move:
                    board[row][col] = 'O'
                    computer_valid_move = True
    return board


def main():
    """The Main Game Loop:"""

    free_cells = 42
    users_turn = True
    ttt_board = [[" ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " "], [" ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " "],
                 [" ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " "], [" ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " "],
                 [" ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " "], [" ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " "],
                 [" ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " "]]

    while not winner(ttt_board) and (free_cells > 0):
        display_board(ttt_board)
        if users_turn:
            ttt_board = make_user_move(ttt_board)
            users_turn = not users_turn
        else:
            ttt_board = make_computer_move(ttt_board)
            users_turn = not users_turn
        free_cells -= 1

    display_board(ttt_board)
    if (winner(ttt_board) == 'X'):
        print("Y O U   W O N !")
    elif (winner(ttt_board) == 'O'):
        print("I   W O N !")
    else:
        print("S T A L E M A T E !")
    print("\n*** GAME OVER ***\n")


# Start the game!
main()
```

However, whenever I run the program and get 4 in a row, it doesn't say that I won or anything. It just continues the program. Hopefully someone can help me out :)

There's another thing. How would I check for row and column winners without having to list out all the possible rows and columns that a win can exist? Is there an efficient way for this?

Thank you so much!

Comment: Please supply the expected [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  Show where the intermediate results differ from what you expected.
We should be able to copy and paste a contiguous block of your code, execute that file, and reproduce your problem along with tracing output for the problem points.  This lets us test our suggestions against your test data and desired output.

Comment: You posted your entire program, without illustrating the specific problem.  We are not going to hand-enter test cases for you and trace the results with added code: that's *your* responsibility.

Comment: Also, you've asked a second question, a very broad one, without doing the expected research or trying an implementation.  Either of these disqualifies the question.  Please repeat [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) from the [intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your winner function has a hard time finding a winner because it just looks at the top left 4 by 4 square. You need to find a way to look at the whole rows and columns for 4 equal in a row.

This code part could check the rows.

```py
for row in range(7):
    i = 0
    last = ''
    for col in range(7):
        this = board[row][col]
        if this == " ":
            i = 0
            continue
        if this == last:
            i+= 1
        else:
            i = 1
        if i >= 4:
            return this
        last = this
```

You could gain performance by only checking the column and row of the latest inserted brick.